# Banking ATM program

Tags: python, class, bank

I wrote a simple program for a banking ATM. The program is working properly, just I don't know how to update the new balance after I made a withdraw or deposit. Because in the menu function, i always set the self._balance back after inputting a pin number. The problem must be in the Bankdatabase, What is the best way to fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by your code structure. That looks like many MANY different classes worth of work to me! I don't have time to write up something more fully-formed, but consider refactoring your code, especially consider that the `__init__` method should initialize all the ATTRIBUTES of a class, which would include things like `self.balance`. Don't use it to invoke front-end routines, do that afterwards with something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     ATM = Savingaccount()
     ATM.menu()
```

If I were you I'd write at minimum class for the ATM that prompts the user and a class for the account that has a balance within it. My code would be something like:

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self,acctholder,balance,pin):
        self.acctholder = acctholder # name
        self._balance = balance # amount as a decimal.Decimal
        self.pin = pin # a hashed pin number
    @staticmethod
    def confirmPIN(pin, hash):
        # hash a given PIN and check it against the hash
    def deposit(self,amount):
        self._balance += amount
    def withdraw(self,amount,pin):
        # hash the pin and check against self.pin
        # if False, raise PermissionError
        else:
            self._balance -= amount
    @property
    def balance(self):
        return self._balance

class ATM(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts = {#hash: <class Account>, ... }
    def menu(self):
        print("All the user options, and handle input and routing here")
```

Comment: I understand your point, but i'm pretty new to python, so how does the hash thing work?

Comment: `import hashlib; help(hashlib)`

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of whether or not a valid PIN has already been entered, and don't prompt for PIN / reinitialize balance if a valid pin has been entered.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  I'm pretty new to python

Comment: In your `__init__` function, initialize a boolen (e.g. `self.pin_entered = False`). When they enter a valid pin, set it to True. Then in your `menu` function, check the value of `self.pin_entered` before you call `self.Bankdatabase()`. I have it working right now, but I'm trying not to write your code for you since this appears to be a class assignment.

Comment: I just tried what you said,but it skipped the whole input pin number part. what am I doing wrong here? I put (self.pin_entered=True) after if I entered a pin(e.g pin=="0704")

Comment: Before i call the self.Bankdatabase(), so i check the boolean value like this? if self.pin_entered==True:? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you really want them to have to re-enter their pin after they already entered it once? I was thinking you wouldn't.

Also `if self.pin_entered==True` is the same as `if self.pin_entered`. Either way checks that the value of `self.pin_entered` is `True`

Comment: I finally figured it out! it should be def Continue(self):self.pin_entered=True and then if self.pin_entered==False: before I call self.Bankdatabase() in the menu()